# MediaPlayer errors

Tags: java, android

I need to write a very simple android application but I have a serious problem.

Here is my class:

```
package com.music.playa;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PlayMusic extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void playSound() {

        try {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;         
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        String[] sounds = { "sound1", "sound2", "sound3" };
        mediaPlayer = null;
        int path = getResources().getIdentifier(
                sounds[new Random().nextInt(sounds.length)], "raw",
                getPackageName());
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, path);

        mediaPlayer
                .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // do something...
                    }
                });

        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

}
```

The problem is that when I press the button all the time calling PlaySound function, then after a while (about 40-50 presses of the button), the console throws a lot of errors:

```
05-28 12:56:00.202: E/MediaPlayer(755): error (-38, 0)
05-28 12:56:01.153: E/MediaPlayer(755): error (-19, 0)
05-28 12:56:01.153: E/MediaPlayer(755): Error (-19,0)
```

and the sound stops playing.

What should I do?

Android SDK 2.3.3

Comment: print your logcat so we can help you, we can't figure what is your error unless you past the exception raised in your logcat and the cause of it
in logcat
Exception.....

Caused By....

Answer (score 0):

You should create your instance of media player as a field of the PlayMedia class and initialise it before you set the onClick listener of your button.

Prepare it in onResume() and release it in onPause().  The only thing your button needs to do is stop/start.